# Matching has more than one value

Tags: c#

I already code a program which can show the equality between two array of text file and my problem is that I have more than one equal value and I only want one value is match with another. can anyone help me on this?

line 2 value on the Left should be match with line 4 value on the right but the output show that line 13 also match:

[image: line 2 value on the Left should be match with line 4 value on the right but the output show that line 13 also match]

here are my code

```
for (int i = 0; i <line.Length; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j <lines.Length; j++)
     {
         if (line[i] == lines[j])
         {
             found = true;
             listBox3.Items.Add("PASS");
             break;
         }

     }

     if (found == false)
     {

         listBox3.Items.Add("FAIL: line " + (i + 1));
     }
     found = false;
 }
```

Comment: so how do you want to handle this case? do you want to just ignore further matches?

Comment: i just want  the result check the equality line by line according the line number

Comment: looking at your code it does exactly that. It will stop checking after the first match. then it will go to the next item in `line`. which will find again a match with `lines[3]` at `line[9]`

Comment: your code works as expected it does not match "Line 13: 5mA "! What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Why should only line 4 match, and not line 13 as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the posted code does not produce the described problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
var areEquals = array1.All(x => array2.Count(y => y == x) == 1);
```